# Detect all objects on position of mouse tap in HERE Maps API

Tags: here-api

If I have few overlapped polygons rendered on the map, can I get all objects at the position of mouse tap?
When I use map.addEventListener('tap', event => console.log(event.target)); it returns only one upper polygon.
Is there any other way to define whether another polygon under detected one exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use use map's method `getObjectsAt()` within your callback:

```js
map.addEventListener('tap', function(evt) {
    var pointer = evt.currentPointer;

    map.getObjectsAt(pointer.viewportX, pointer.viewportY, function(objects) {
        console.log(objects);
    });
})
```

For more details see [H.Map#getObjectsAt](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.Map.html#getObjectsAt) documentation.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It's really what I need.